# roslocate info turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays, I get the result and I did this command  In workspace that have .rosinstall:

rosws merge https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot -t .

But I receive a error:

ERROR: Invalid multiproject yaml format in [https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot]: mapping values are not allowed here
in "", line 8, column 27

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41867/roslocate-info-turtlebot/) by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on 2012-08-20**:
Ok...but I you can see that I try to do this : http://answers.ros.org/question/41785/roslocate-info-turtlebot-rosws-merge-/

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-20**:
And as the answer indicates, there is a bug in current rosws. I'll edit my answer to show how to still add the output of roslocate.

**Comment by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on 2012-08-20**:
Thanks a lot! I have another problem when I use " rows update  ". Itry to correct here! Thanks again!

**Comment by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on 2012-08-20**:
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'turtlebot' : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

ERROR: Error processing 'turtlebot' : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct command (also used on the wiki page) is:

```
roslocate info turtlebot | rosws merge -
rosws update
```

**Edit**: Unfortunately, it seems like `rosws` has a bug right now that might prevent you from executing above command. Assuming you are using ROS fuerte, to assume the same effect as above, you can do the following:

```
roscd
roslocate info turtlebot >> .rosinstall
rosws update
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1